# Jquery-Fetch links in an Array

Tags: jquery

I have an webpage and I want to get all the links in an arrayset.
My page has elements stacked up something like this:

```
<ul class='abc'
<li>
<div>
<h3> <a href="www.1.com"> hey1</a>
     <span class="xyz">  heyxyz </span>
</h3>
</div>
</li>
<ul>
```

Similarly I have 17 **UL** elements with the same class that goes on like this.

My aim is to capture

- www.1.com
- Hey 1
- heyxyz

in an array. 
When i do an

> $('.abc')
>   
> in google developer tools.
>   I get all my 17 `**<ul class="abc">**` elements.

This is as far as i could go (i am very new to Jquery.)

Please help me dig this process out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` method and create an array of objects:

```
var arr = $('.abc').map(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return {
        'a_href':    $this.find('a').attr('href'),
        'a_text':    $this.find('a').text(),
        'span_text': $this.find('span.xyz').text()
    };    
}).get();
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand this. I just need to be able to parse after i get in the elements . Is there any other way to get it into an array?(i would require 3 such arrays).

Comment: @BoyLittUp As I said this creates an array of objects. One object for each `ul`. You can also use the jQuery `.each()` method and `.push()` the desired values into an array (_if this makes sense_).